# expected exception throwed on javafx (trying to implement concurrency)

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, javafx

I'm a newbie on javafx and I want to implement concurrency on my project, which allows me to code a multithreading app. To do that, I did the following:

```
Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
@Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {

        /// long task...
        sitioFind(); // downloads text from a website (HttpStatusException is always thrown and that's when the long task freezes)


        newEpi();  //downloads an image from a website (the program never reaches this point of the code because it freezes before).

       //Notice that the UI doesn't freeze. The UI thread seems to be working fine because it never freezes. The problem is with the running task: exception thrown, program stops working.

   return null;
     }
   };
new Thread(task).start();
```

The code that enables multithreading works fine (the long task is executed and the UI is updated simultaneously). But, this works good if and only if the **long task**  doesn't throw any exception.

If any exception are thrown, the app just freezes and stops doing the long task and, therefore, the UI is not updated.

So, what I did was to research on javaFX documentation, and I found some text:

> The state of a Worker object that completes successfully is SUCCEEDED, and the value property is set to the result of this Worker object. **Otherwise, if any exceptions are thrown during the execution of the Worker object, its state becomes FAILED and the exception property is set to the type of the exception that occurred**

So, according to the previous paragraph, the state became FAILED and the program didn't go on because of that. The code will always throw an exception (the exception needs to be thrown and it's strictly needed to be that way) but the state goes FAILED and the program doesn't go on.

What I need is a way to avoid the program state to become FAILED, or a way to prevent the UI from getting freezed when the program state changes. Thanks .

Comment: Do you have a `catch block` for your exception ?

Comment: You probably need to give a bit more detail here. If you are updating the UI from `Platform.runLater(..)` calls inside the `call(...)` method, then it's not clear why it wouldn't work. If you are using a `setOnSucceeded(...)` handler, then you can similarly use a `setOnFailed(...)` handler to handle the case where the `call(...)` method throws an exception. Note it's generally a really bad idea to use exceptions for logical control.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Yes , but the app acts as if I don't. When the HttpStatusException is thrown, the long task stops.

Comment: @James_D I'm updating the UI directly from `call(...)`method. I have a label called "stateLabel" which shows info about the current task. Inside the call method, I just write `stateLabel.setText("info about current task");` . I'm not using any of those handlers, but I will try.
PD. I updated the code of my question with more details.

Comment: That's not legal (see [Javadocs for Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html), for example). You must update the UI on the FX Application thread.

Comment: ok. so you mean outside the call method?

Comment: As stated, your description doesn't really make any sense. If the first method "always" throws an exception, then the second method will never be executed. That's nothing to do with threading or the Task API, it's just the normal rules of Java exceptions. What's your evidence that the long task "freezes"?

Comment: the first method always throws an exception but that exception is catched by a `catch block`, then the second method can be executed. I can realize the long task freezes because it is supposed to download a file and display its progress on the console, but that's not happening. On the other hand, the UI does not freeze anymore.